# WPF - positioning with dynamically canvas

Tags: wpf, canvas, position

I have the following code:

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas Grid.Row="0" x:Name="drawingSurface" Background="White" ClipToBounds="True"
            MouseLeftButtonDown="drawingSurface_MouseLeftButtonDown"
            MouseLeftButtonUp="drawingSurface_MouseLeftButtonUp" 
            MouseMove="drawingSurface_MouseMove">
    </Canvas>
    <Grid Name="pnlProperties" Visibility="Hidden"/>
</Grid>
```

After starting this window, the user selects his interested area (I catch `MouseMove`, `MouseLeftButtonDown`, `MouseLeftButtonUp`).

Then I want to show the panel pnlProperties under the selected area in the left corner (in my interested coordinates).

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `Grid` into the `Canvas`, and then set the coordinates for the `Grid`, using:

```
 YourCanvas.SetLeft(pnlProperties, MOUSE.X)
 YourCanvas.SetTop(pnlProperties, MOUSE.Y);
```

Comment: can I do it without changing XAML (important)?

Comment: Why is it important? I see no reason. You can also ditch the canvas concept and add TranslateTransform to your grid, and play with X/Y.